# Call other extension Observer in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

Am integrating existing address validation extension in Onestepcheckout extension. Existing address validation is called via observer.After shipping address is given, following coding is used to call address validation extension.

```
<controller_action_predispatch>
    <observers>
        <webshopapps_wsavalidation>
             <class>wsavalidation/observer</class>
             <method>hookToControllerActionPreDispatch</method>
         </webshopapps_wsavalidation>
     </observers>
</controller_action_predispatch>
<controller_action_postdispatch>
    <observers>
        <webshopapps_wsavalidationpost>
             <class>wsavalidation/observer</class>
             <method>hookToControllerActionPostDispatch</method>
         </webshopapps_wsavalidationpost>
     </observers>
</controller_action_postdispatch>
```

I've added this coding in my extension. It does't works. What should be given?

*Note:Am trying to incorporate all working functionalists in Address validation extension to Onestepcheckout.*

Comment: What's exactly your question?

Comment: I want to incorporate all working functionalists in Address validation extension to Onestepcheckout.My above way not right?